# Getting MTA blocked from zen.spamhaus.org but the website check shows IP is OK

Tags: amazon-ses

I'm using zen.spamhaus.org in my sendmail config.
FEATURE(`dnsbl',`zen.spamhaus.org')dnl

I'm using AWS SES to send email and when I try to relay an email I get:
Nov  9 09:01:00 Web-Mail sendmail[12751]: ruleset=check_relay, arg1=e226-2.smtp-out.us-east-2.amazonses.com, arg2=127.255.255.254, relay=e226-2.smtp-out.us-east-2.amazonses.com [23.251.226.2], reject=550 5.7.1 Rejected: 23.251.226.2 listed at zen.spamhaus.org

But if I go to the the spamhaus website and check the IP it says there are no issues.
https://check.spamhaus.org/not_listed/?searchterm=23.251.226.2
23.251.226.2 has no issues

This has just started happening recently. I tried white listing the SES server in my access.db to no avail.
Any help would be appreciated.

I tried white listing the SES server in my access.db to no avail.
Also tried sbl.spamhaus.org with the same results.

Turns out it's also blocking other valid MTA's
Nov  9 09:43:26 Web-Mail sendmail[12990]: ruleset=check_relay, arg1=mail-dm6nam10olkn2106.outbound.protection.outlook.com, arg2=127.255.255.254, relay=mail-dm6nam10olkn2106.outbound.protection.outlook.com [40.92.41.106], reject=550 5.7.1 Rejected: 40.92.41.106 listed at zen.spamhaus.org

Which explains why I'm getting reports from other people saying their emails are being returned.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing a similar issue, lots of people receiving rejected email notices because of zen.spamhaus.org wrongly sending blocked responses.

As you have found going to the spamhaus website indicates no issues with the ips.

But this is the only mention of the issue that I can find!

I am using postfix

I ahve removed zen.spamhause.org from my smtpd_recipient_restrictions config for now and things are returning to normal.

Looks like the DNS for zen.spamhaus.org isn't resolving. Could be the issue

---

Ok looks like I was rate limited - I am working on a project that sent my 203 emails in error. I think I fell foul of samhaus's rate limiter for too many queries in a short time.

Comment: Yes, it does look like zen.spamhaus.org is not resolving. I've tried a number of dns servers to no avail trying to find it's ip address.

Comment: Your actual answer is really useful, but submitting an answer before investigating all possible issues can sometimes lead to misleading information (remember, not everybody reads answers to the end...)

Answer (score 1):

Spamhaus will not allow you to use their service if you use one of the public DNS servers to access them. Make sure you are using your provider's DNS server and the DNS server is not listed as public on their list.

For example running:

nslookup 5.5.5.5.zen.spamhaus.org 1.1.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:

Name:   5.5.5.5.zen.spamhaus.org
Address: 127.255.255.254

will always fail. (1.1.1.1 is public DNS server)

https://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage#243

Hope this helps.